# Google Chart -- add "recession bars"

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a Google Chart that works great. To add context to this chart, I need to add a series in the background that distinguishes weekends visually. The desired effect shown as applied to recession periods rather than weekends is at the bottom. Is it possible to create this effect using Google Visualization?

[image]

Here is the chart:

```
          <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
              var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
... DATA ...

              ]);
              var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(
                {prefix: '$', negativeColor: 'red', negativeParens: true});
              formatter.format(data, 1); // Apply formatter to second column
              formatter.format(data, 2); // Apply formatter to second column
              formatter.format(data, 3); // Apply formatter to second column

              var options = {isStacked: true, vAxis: {format: '$#,###'}, title:"MTS Revenue" };        
              var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
              chart.draw(data, options);
            }
          </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can accomplish this effect with a [ComboChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart).

The general concept is to make your stacked bar chart, and then add a series that shows the max value of your chart as a separate column on weekends, and plot that series as a steppedArea chart. This will make it look like a background for certain series.

Here is an example (copy paste in to [Google Playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#combo_chart)):

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador', 'Madagascar', 'Papua New Guinea', 'Rwanda', 'Average'],
    ['2004/05',  165,      938,         522,             998,           450,      0],
    ['2005/06',  135,      1120,        599,             1268,          288,      4000],
    ['2006/07',  157,      1167,        587,             807,           397,      0],
    ['2007/08',  139,      1110,        615,             968,           215,      4000],
    ['2008/09',  136,      691,         629,             1026,          366,      0]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  var ac = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  ac.draw(data, {
    title : 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    vAxis: {title: "Cups", minValue: 0, maxValue: 4000},
    hAxis: {title: "Month"},
    seriesType: "bars",
    isStacked: true,
    series: {5: {type: "steppedArea", lineWidth: 0, showInLegend: false}}
  });
}
```